# Fragment 2 pane windowSoftInputMode for soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

[image]

I am facing issues when soft keyboard opens up on my 2 pane layout as seen above.
For the left side list view fragment i want to `adjustPan` the soft input. If i don't do this then when the soft keyboard closes it leaves back blank space on the list fragment.
For the right side detail pane i want to `adjestResize` the soft input so that user can enter text into both edit texts and click button with soft keyboard still open.
I tried setting the properties differently for my fragments in their respective `onCreateView()` using `setSoftInputMode()` but that did not help me much because both fragments got `adjustResize` finally.
Any solutions/ideas which will help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> to ensure that the system resizes your layout to the available
>   space—which ensures that all of your layout content is accessible
>   (even though it probably requires scrolling)—use "adjustResize":

```
<application ... >
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
    ...
</activity>
...
```

Please go through this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)